# laravel: How to retrieve POST data through ajax in controller

Tags: jquery, controller, laravel

I'm trying to retrieve `$_POST` data submitted through jquery ajax func but there seem to be nothing passed. Here is my code: first my form:

```
{{  Form::open('', 'POST', array('id'=>'ajax')) }}

    {{ Form::text('_date', '', array('id'=>'datepicker', 'class'=>'app_date')) }}
    {{ Form::submit('Go', array('id'=>'go')) }}

{{  Form::close() }}
```

And jquery:

```
$('#ajax').submit(function(e){

    $.ajax({
        url: 'appajax',
        type: 'POST',
        data: $('.app_date').val(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(info){
                     console.log(info);
         }
    });

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

... and finally in the controller:

```
public function post_appajax()
    {

        return Response::json(Input::get('_date'));

    }
```

And in console the output is `NULL`. What I'm I missing? I'm using laravel 3 currently downloadable from laravel.com. Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you are using POST method you should pass a key/value pair instead of a string, an object, change:

```
data: $('.app_date').val(),
```

to:

```
data: { _date: $('.app_date').val() },
```

Comment: sorry, but how do i mark the answer as "solution"? Help, wanna be a good citizen :)

Comment: oh i think i figured it out... the tick sign on left... says "click to accept answer" ... i'm getting there :)